# how are realtime database systems different from timeseries databases

Tags: database, time-series, multiple-databases

I understand time series databases like influxDB etc... are used to store metrics or variables that change over time. eg uses would be to store sensor data or metrics like counters and timers.

How different is it from a realtime database since timeseries data too is realtime in a sense. Can I use timeseries db for realtime data or vice-versa.Else, is there a database that handles both?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing time-series data, relational or non?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814167/storing-time-series-data-relational-or-non)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time-series database is a database that stores values distributed over time (timestamp + value array for each series).

A real-time database is a database that satisfies real-time guarantees and should meet some time constraints and deadlines. E.g. the database system can guarantee that the query will be executed in no longer than 100ms. If it takes longer, the error will be triggered. Any database system can be real-time, e.g. a relational one or KV-store. A good example of such systems are the ticker plants used by stock exchanges (NYSE, TSX or NASDAQ).

TLDR
Real-time database and time-series database are two different things.