# Functional dependency in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-normalization

Lets say there are warehouses each storing items of a specific type.

So there are tables with fields

- Warehouse - ID,Name,Type
- Item - ID,Name,Type
- WarehouseItem - Warehouse, Item
- Type - ID, Name

The question is - given that a Warehouse only holds Items with of specific Type, what database normalization rule is this breaking?

Is this database normalized?

(The problem's example is made up, but I basically have this problem in real life.)

Comment: in this case, more than breaking one of the rules for normalisation, i'd say your schema is implementing a different database than your requirements. (if a warehouse will only contain items of the same type, the type goes in relation with the warehouse).

Comment: Not exactly, I think. A warehouse doesn't contain all the items of a given type. You are probably correct that there should be a Type table and a Warehouse.Type field. But the Warehouse still contains only some of those items.

Would not mark as resolved yet. I will edit to clarify.

Comment: I did not say to make to make the warehouse.type field unique, only that if the relation exists, it must be materialized. Multiple warehouses would still be able to have the same item type (but only one type each).

Comment: I will add the relation, but I guess the question still remains. Is it normalized? I will edit again. Please add an answer if you have one. (Why do you comment instead?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm making some assumptions from just looking at your metadata without any data examples, but on first glance it appears that your schema for the most part is normalized. Technically speaking your table is 3NF (which should be your target) if it meets all of the following standards:

- It is also [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) - Each entry only contains atomic data (or a single piece of info)
- It is also [2NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form) - No candidate key dependency meaning that when you have have a [composite primary key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key) (a key made up of more than one column) that all data is dependent on the *entire* key
- It is [3NF](http://www.1keydata.com/database-normalization/third-normal-form-3nf.php) - No [transitive dependency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_dependency) meaning all data is only dependent on the [primary key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_key) and not some other column in the table

*Note that there are also higher normalized forms but they are mostly academic as you begin experiencing performance degradation the more you normalize*

Given this definition:

- `Warehouse` appears 3NF assuming that each warehouse can only have one `Type`. If not then you would be failing the transitive dependency and would need to move `Type` information to a new table.
- `Item` too appears 3NF assuming only one `Type` can be assigned
- `Type` appears to contain redundant data and should be removed unless of course you have a `many-to-many` relationship between `Type` and `Warehouse` and/or `Item`. In that case, you would want to introduce a [`bridge-entity`](http://yukidatabase.blogspot.com/2012/08/composite-entities-think-back-to.html) (aka `composite entry`) between `Type` and `Warehouse` or `Item` to create two `1-to-many` relationships.
- Lastly, if I'm reading this correctly, `WarehouseItem` appears to be a bridge-entity between `Warehouse` and `Item` to break up the `many-to-many` relationship between them. If this is correct, you should be able to argue that this table is 3NF assuming the combination of `Warehouse` and `Item` represent a `composite key`.

So assuming I interpreted your schema correctly, once you eliminate the redundant `Type` table, then yes I would say this setup technically meets 3NF. Note that your requirement that

> given that a Warehouse only holds Items with of specific Type

may require you introduce a new *type* field which will mean you need to reevaluate your normalization of that table. If you have two distinct types (a *`WarehouseType`* and an *`ItemType`*) then you may need to keep that `Type` table after all and turn it into a mapping table between those two new fields. But I'd need to see data examples to better evaluate.

Comment: The problem is that the relations don't prevent a Warehouse from having Items of multiple Types. I thought this was a sign that it's not in some normal form.

But you seem to imply that the problem can't be solved with normalization. Marked as correct answer.

Comment: That should be relatively easily fixed by adding a constraint to your WarehouseItem table to ensure a match must exist. MySQL handles constraints a little differently then other databases but you can find more info here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraints.html

Comment: "Note that there are also higher normalized forms but they are mostly academic as you begin experiencing performance degradation the more you normalize" - This is untrue and dangerous to be telling people. I've often seen that normalized schemas perform *better* than denormalized ones in certain query engines and patterns. https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2008/07/21/the-myth-of-over-normalization/

Comment: @NWest Interesting article... I'd be interested to see data quantifying his proposal. Still, "untrue and dangerous" is a stretch... Mr. Davis is bucking industry and academic precedent. If he is right then more power to him... but, pragmatically, I think you are going to have a hard time finding customers who will justify the development cost for increased normalization on a database. 3NF is still a worthy endeavor and sadly a rarity in the real world.

Comment: @NWest Something else worth mentioning... it's not just database performance you have to take into account but also the ability of a developer or BI user to interact with the tables. There is an inverse relationship of ease-of-use with normalization so in saving 20 seconds querying time you might be adding hours to future development proposals. Still your point is well taken... I'll have to further research myself.

Comment: Example here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4394183/should-olap-databases-be-denormalized-for-read-performance/4731664#4731664