# r data.table function wrapper around ad-hoc join (with aggregation in a chain)

Tags: r, function, join, data.table, wrapper

[data.table_1.9.6]
background of the question is that I am trying to build olap-like query features in a star-schema-like data layout, i.e. a large fact table and several meta tables. I am building a function wrapper around data.table join followed by an aggregation in a chain as so:

```
# dummy data
dt1 = data.table(id = 1:5, x=letters[1:5], a=11:15, b=21:25)
dt2 = data.table(k=11:15, z=letters[11:15])

# standard data.table query with ad-hoc key -> works fine
dt1[dt2, c("z") := .(i.z), with = F, 
    on = c(a="k")][, .(m = sum(a, na.rm = T),
                   count = .N), by = c("z")]

# wrapper function with setkey -> works fine
agg_foo <- function(x, meta_tbl, x_key, meta_key, agg_var) { 
  setkeyv(x, x_key)
  setkeyv(meta_tbl, meta_key)
  x[meta_tbl, (agg_var) := get(agg_var)][,.(a_sum = sum(a, na.rm=T),
                                            count = .N), 
                                         by = c(agg_var)]
  x[, (agg_var) := .(NULL)]
  }

# call function (works fine)
agg_foo(x=dt1, meta_tbl=dt2, x_key="a", meta_key="k",agg_var="z")

# wrapper function with ad-hoc key -> does not work
agg_foo_ad_hoc <- function(x, meta_tbl, x_key, meta_key, agg_var) { 
  x[meta_tbl, (agg_var) := get(agg_var), 
    on = c(x_key = meta_key)][,.(a_sum = sum(a, na.rm=T),
                                 count = .N), by = c(agg_var)]
  x[, (agg_var) := .(NULL)]
  }

# call function (causes error)
agg_foo_ad_hoc(x=dt1, meta_tbl=dt2, x_key="a", meta_key="k",agg_var="z")

Error in forderv(x, by = rightcols) : 
  'by' value -2147483648 out of range [1,4]
```

my guess is that I have to provide the ad-hoc "on" parameter in a different way. I tried on = c(get(x_key) = meta_key) but then he is complaining about unexpected brackets. I could go with setkey version of the function that works but I wonder if this is efficient given that the function will work on different meta tables depending on which attribute for the aggregation is used and thus constantly re-setting the key. or is the setkey always to be preferred? actual fact table (x here) has > 30 mln rows.

Comment: You may want to check [data.cube](https://github.com/jangorecki/data.cube) package which defines OLAP cube R data type, based on set of data.tables. In the package there is `cube` class which is star schema modeled. In devel branch *data.cube-oop* there is a new `data.cube` class which is a mix of star and snowflake schema, described in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472639/star-schema-normalized-dimensions-denormalized-hierarchy-level-keys). It automatically sub-aggregate to available dimensions and keeps the data in cube normalized.

Comment: @jangorecki: I know about your package. already looked into it in the past. thanks for the tip anyway! I would also gladly go through its github source if it wasn't blocked by corporate IT. but is there a data.table only implementation?

Comment: The actual upstream repo is on [gitlab.com/jangorecki/data.cube](https://gitlab.com/jangorecki/data.cube), so you may try there. Implementation is based on `data.table` and [big.data.table](https://github.com/jangorecki/big.data.table) for fact table (and only partially for `cube` class so far). The latter one allows to distribute fact table over multiple machines, removing the memory limits and allowing parallelized queries, capable to process OLAP big data efficiently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is construct a vector with correct labels. Here's one way of doing that:

```
agg_foo_ad_hoc <- function(x, meta_tbl, x_key, meta_key, agg_var) { 
  x[meta_tbl, (agg_var) := get(agg_var), 
    on = setNames(meta_key, x_key)][,.(a_sum = sum(a, na.rm=T),
                                       count = .N), by = c(agg_var)]
  x[, (agg_var) := .(NULL)]
}
```

Comment: do you have an opinion on function design, i.e. whether setkey is to be preferred over ad-hoc key?

Comment: @Triam nowadays I'm using `on` almost exclusively. It's more flexible, and I like knowing what I'm doing within each operation, as opposed to having used `setkey` in some other part of the code and then having to remember that I'd done that. The only case where I'd use `setkey` now, is if I need to do multiple joins/lookups in a row on the same key.